# VB.NET VS 2012 Could not load file or assembly 'AgtPBAPI

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am studying VB.NET for school project
I am using VB.NET and VS 2012 to build sw

I built install package and I installed sw where in my another laptop.

When I was running sw with VS 2012 it was working fine.

However, After I installed sw(not using VS 2012), I am getting error

> Cound not load file ot assembly 'AgtPBAPI Version = 2.0.4363.25737
>   Culture=neutral. Publickey Token -......' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system connot find the file specified

I am not really sure why this happen. I coded and built laptop 1 and then I install sw to laptop 2

When I was running source code on the laptop 2, it was working fine. (using VS 2012)

However, after I installed sw to laptop 2 and run sw then i was display system message above.

I tried to changed app.config to run .NET 4.0 but it didn't work

Is any solution to fix this problem ?

thanks

Comment: `2012 - .NET 4.5` change framework 4 to 4.5

Comment: Hi Sathish thanks for helping me. I just change to 4.5.1, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: 64 bit CPU or 32 bit? Check that both laptops are the same, if laptop 2 is different - then you need to build the application differently for your software to run properly